# Ansible stat, register and when while looping

Tags: ansible

I have this:

```
   - stat: path=/etc/pki/tls/certs/{{ item.ServerName }}.crt
     with_items:
       - "{{ prod }}"
     register: sslcheck

   - debug: var=sslcheck

   - name: Create self-signed SSL cert
     command: openssl req -new -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=IT/CN=${item.ServerName}" -days 3650 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/{{item.ServerName}}.key -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/{{item.ServerName}}.crt -extensions v3_ca creates=/etc/pki/tls/certs/{{item.ServerName}}.crt
     with_items:
       - "{{ prod }}"
     when: sslcheck.results.stat.exists == False
```

However, my condition does not work... When I debug, I still see the result: false or true for sslcheck.results.stat.exists

So, why it doesn't work ?

RESULT:

```
fatal: [httpd1] => error while evaluating conditional: sslcheck.results.stat.exists
fatal: [httpd2] => error while evaluating conditional: sslcheck.results.stat.exists
fatal: [httpd3] => error while evaluating conditional: sslcheck.results.stat.exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do the `.results` come from?`

If you read the [stat module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html), I think you should check with:

`when: sslcheck.stat.exists == False`

Comment: It comes from the loop (`with_items`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881763/7976758.